# Using Firebug with Knockout causes "unresponsive script error"

Tags: firefox, knockout.js, firebug

I'm building a screen with Knockout using Firefox with Firebug open on the page.

In a very specific case I get an unresponsive script error from Firefox and after much testing I've narrowed it down to only happen in this specific case when Firebug is open. When it is closed I don't get the error.

After stepping through the Knockout debug js a number of times with this error I've found that the first "unresponsive script" popup occurs near the processing of end comment (1807)

```
setDomNodeChildren: function(node, childNodes) {
                        if (!isStartComment(node))
                            ko.utils.setDomNodeChildren(node, childNodes);
                        else {
                            ko.virtualElements.emptyNode(node);
                            var endCommentNode = node.nextSibling; // Must be the next sibling, as we just emptied the children
                            for (var i = 0, j = childNodes.length; i < j; i++)
                                endCommentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(childNodes[i], endCommentNode);
                        }
                    },
```

or near 1728 which is also near work about the end comment

```
function isEndComment(node) {
                    return (node.nodeType == 8) && (commentNodesHaveTextProperty ? node.text : node.nodeValue).match(endCommentRegex);
                }
```

but it's in a different location each time and if I click 'continue' on the unresponsive script popup I can just keep going.

Running without Firebug gives no error and running in Chrome with or without developer tools gives no error.

I'm at a loss as to what to try or what code to post to help resolve my problem as I've made many screens with Knockout using Firefox and Firebug and this is the first time I've run into a problem like this.

But I would very much appreciate any hints or advice as to how to get firebug to stop causing this problem. (Although maybe I'll just have to move to Chrome...)

Answer (score 0):

the unresponsive script is when the script takes to long and with the fire bug attached it is bit slower making the difference between success and time out, you can just ignore the error, the error it's on different locations because it can run different amounts of code till time out.

But your script is to close to time out so check to see if you can optimize it.